# Single Sign On with subdomains on the same server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

How I can implement single sign-on with two subdomains?

- app1.domain.com
- app2.domain.com

I already created the virtual host with Apache on my local machine, so I have two Laravel projects: app1.domain.com and app2.domain.com

I would like that when I log in to a subdomain the other subdomain should be logged with the same session

I tried to configure the .env file and config/session.php:

### app1

.env

```
APP_KEY=base64:qs1+/YjtqEPjS3HUYC/PaDDQk51gWY0H4iw6eAG0RF8=

APP_URL=http://app1.domain.com/

SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.com
```

config/session.php

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.domain.com'),
```

### app2

.env

```
APP_KEY=base64:qs1+/YjtqEPjS3HUYC/PaDDQk51gWY0H4iw6eAG0RF8=

APP_URL=http://app2.domain.com/

SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.com
```

config/session.php

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', '.domain.com'),
```

This doesn't work, when one subdomain is logged the other is not logged in, How can I implement a SSO with Laravel, if there any package for Laravel 5.4?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try pointing the 'Session File Location' to the same directory (in config/session.php)?

You might need to hard code the directory in one of config files.

**app1**: config/session.php

```
'files' => storage_path().'/framework/sessions',
```

**app2**: config/session.php

```
'files' => /path/to/app1/storage/framework/sessions',
```

Another option might be to use a database driver and point to the same table.